# Java and MySQL: More than 'max_user_connections' exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

For university, it is my excercise to develop a multiplayer game with Java. The communication between the clients shall not be handled with sockets or the like, but with the help of a MySQL database where the clients are adding their steps in the game. Because it is a game of dice, not a lot of queries are needed. (approximiately 30 queries per gaming session are needed).

I never used MySQL in connection with Java before, so this maybe is a beginner's fault. But actually, I often get an exception during the execution of my java project.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User my_username already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

My queries are executed in a DatabaseHelper.java class. The results are returned and evaluated in another class of the project. Since I use an MVC pattern, I evaluate the results in a controller or model class.

This for example is one of my quers in the DatabaseHelper.java class. The other queries are similar:

```
private static Connection conn;

private Connection getConn() {

    return conn;
}

public void db_connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    // JDBC Klassen laden
    Class.forName(dbClassName);

    // Verbindungsversuch auf 5 Sekunden setzen
    DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5); 
    this.setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p)); // p contains the username and the database
}

public void db_close(){

    try {
        this.getConn().close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if(GLOBALVARS.DEBUG)
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String[] query_myHighscores(int gameid, PlayerModel p) throws SQLException{

    List<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    PreparedStatement stmnt;
    if(gameid == GLOBALVARS.DRAGRACE)
        stmnt = this.getConn().prepareStatement("SELECT score FROM highscore WHERE gid = ? and pname = ? ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 0,3");
    else
        stmnt = this.getConn().prepareStatement("SELECT score FROM highscore WHERE gid = ? and pname = ? ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,3");

    stmnt.setInt(1, gameid);
    stmnt.setString(2, p.getUname());

    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery();

    rs.beforeFirst();
    while(rs.next()){
        rowValues.add(rs.getString(1));
    }

    stmnt.close();
    rs.close();

    return (String[])rowValues.toArray(new String[rowValues.size()]);
}
```

The CONNECTION string is a string which looks like jdbc:mysql://my_server/my_database

In the HighscoreGUI.java class, I request the data like this:

```
private void actualizeHighscores(){

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();

    try{
       db.db_connect();
       String[] myScoreDragrace = db.query_myHighscores(GLOBALVARS.GAME1); // id of the game as parameter
       // using the string
   } finally {
        db.db_close();
   }
```

So I tried:

- Closing the statement and the ResultSet after each query
- Used db_close() to close the connection to the dabase in the finally-block
- Never returning a ResultSet (found out this may become a performance leak)

The stacktrace leads in the DatabaseHelper.java class to the line

> ```
>   this.setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p));
> ```

But I cannot find my mistake why I still get this exception.

I cannot change every settings for the database since this is a shared host. So I'd prefer a solution on Java side.

Comment: If your db queries are executed concurrently the no of active sessions may exceed the limit, anyway you should try to reuse the dbconnection or use a dbconnection pool (provided via a framework like DBCP http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)

Comment: Try storing the connection and only create a new one if it bugs out. IIRC calling close() on a connection is only guaranteed to clean up resources on Java's side.

Comment: @KristapsBaumanis No. close closes the connection in every but the most bizarre situations. Reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you exceed your allowed set of connections to that database. Most likely this limit is exactly or very close to "1". So as soon as you request your second connection your program crashes.

You can solve this by using a connection pooling system like [commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).
That is the recommended way of doing it and the other solution below is only if you may not use external resources.

If you are prohibited in the external code that you might use with your solution you can do this:

Create a "Database" class. This class and only this class ever connects to the DB and it does so only once per program run. You set it up, it connects to the database and then all the queries are created and run through this class, in Java we call this construct a "singleton". It usually has a `private` constructor and a `public static` method that returns the one and only instance of itself. You keep this connection up through the entire livetime of your program and only reactivate it if it gets stall. Basically you implement a "Connection Pool" for the specific case of the pool size "1".

```
public class Database {
   private static final Database INSTANCE = new Database();
   private Database() {}
   public static Database getInstance() {
      return INSTANCE;
   }
   // add your methods here.
}
```

When the program terminates, close the Connection (using a shutdown hook).